# Command prompt started from batch file closes when operation is stopped

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using a batch file to open a number of command prompts while I do some development work, however, I often need to restart 1 or more of the programs, while I'm debugging.
Is it possible to change the code to keep the window open to allow me to restart the application?

```
C:\
cd /d "C:\Users\me\mydir"
start redis-server
start celery worker -A celery_worker.celery --loglevel=info
start python manage.py runserver
```

I'd like to be able to kill and restart the celery worker / webserver whenever I make a change to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`START` attempts to start the program directly; if the program uses `stdin` and `stdout`, this will invoke the console host to handle it. If you want a window that will remain open, instead of using `START`, try `CMD /K` - for the `celery` command line specifically, change `start celery ...` to `CMD /K celery ...`. This starts a command prompt and runs the specified command; if the command terminates, the command prompt will remain, waiting for input (and will remain open until you `exit` it). Look at the output of `CMD /?`, or the [page on `cmd` at SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) for more information.

Comment: `start` creates the process with a flag that instructs it to create a new console, but only if it's flagged as a console application. This isn't directly related to using standard I/O.

Comment: Perhaps not, but I believe that any app that uses standard I/O does end up getting marked as a console app.

Comment: MSVC selects the application type based on the entry point -- e.g. `wmain` (console) vs `wWinMain` (GUI).

Comment: Standard I/O is certainly related. The parameters for a process includes `StandardInput`, `StandardOutput`, and `StandardError` handle values. These are either implicitly copied from the parent process or manually set in the `STARTUPINFO`. For a non-console (GUI) process, the handle values are valid if the handles were inheritable in the parent and the process was created with handle inheritance. For a console process, there's a fourth `ConsoleHandle` that, along with the standard handles, gets implicitly inherited, unless the process creation is flagged to create a new console.

Comment: By changing the `start` to `CMD /K` it appears to want to start each program in the same command terminal, one after the other.
The tasks are no longer run in parallel CMD prompts.

Comment: Interesting. You might want to try `Start CMD/K Celery...` which should get you the best of both worlds - something that Microsoft seems to be constitutionally opposed to...

Comment: @AllynH, why would you expect anything else? CMD is a console application. It inherits the console -- if the parent has one. `start cmd /k` has the shell allocate a new console and run the given command. Note that, unless it's a shell command, it's not running in a "CMD prompt". It runs attached to the console that's inherited from CMD, while CMD waits with its single thread blocked in `WaitForSingleObject` on the process handle. The console is hosted separately in conhost.exe.

Comment: Jeff, I can confirm the code:
`start CMD /K` worked for me, (I can't seem to mark your comment as an answer, so I've marked the main comment as an answer). Thanks very much!

Comment: @eryksun Something wen't wrong the first time I tried the suggested answer `start CMD /K` is working for me now. I can now create several CMD shells, with the correct programs running, then restart each as needed from it's shell.